# Multiple audio files in HTML, if two are clicked the older one should stop playing

Tags: javascript, audio

I have images on my webpage that when clicked they play a sound.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<span div="2" class="sound" onclick="playSound(this,'sounds/activity_1/letter_m_a_1_correct_v2.mp3');">
    <img src="../../images/rainforest/letter_m/activity_1/a1_monkey.png" width="324px" height="274px" alt="Monkey" onclick="showPanelGroup_2();" />
</span>

<span div="3" class="sound" onclick="playSound(this,'sounds/activity_1/letter_m_a_1_incorrect_b.mp3');">
    <img src="../../images/rainforest/letter_m/activity_1/a1_butterfly.png" width="324px" height="274px" alt="Butterfly" />
</span>
```

I am currently using the following Javascript code to pause and play one sound at a time when clicked:

```
function playSound(el,soundfile) {
              if (el.mp3) {
                  if(el.mp3.paused) el.mp3.play();
                  else el.mp3.pause();
              } else {
                  el.mp3 = new Audio(soundfile);
                  el.mp3.play();
              }
         }
```

If both of the images are clicked the sounds will overlap.  I need for first sound to stop playing as soon as the second image is clicked and for the second sound to play.

Comment: What is `div="..."`? This is not well-formed HTML. Did you mean `id="..."`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new MP3 player for each element when you pass `this` to the function in your `onclick`.

You either need to use a single element to hold the player, in which case you can overwrite what is playing on each click, or you need to have each click send the pause signal to *all the other players on the page*.

The benefit of keeping a separate player for each one (as you are doing now) is that each one retains its progress, so that it will resume when you click it again, so that's the example that I will stay with.

Here's an example of pausing all of the other players when you click on any one of them:

```
function pauseOthers(elements, me) {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(el) {
        if (el == me) { return; }

        if (el.mp3) {
            el.mp3.pause();
        }
    });
}

function playSound(el, soundfile) {
    var allPlayers = document.getElementsByClassName('sound');
    pauseOthers(allPlayers, el);

    if (el.mp3) {
        if(el.mp3.paused) el.mp3.play();
        else el.mp3.pause();
    } else {
        el.mp3 = new Audio(soundfile);
        el.mp3.play();
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked!  Thank you Moshe, the sound now pauses when a second item is clicked.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: @Sal Glad to hear that. If an answer worked for you, please click the checkmark next to it to help future visitors see that this is the correct solution.